# How to print and refer to system properties with JBoss CLI Wildfly?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, jboss-cli

Isn't it possible to echo system variables in JBoss ClI?

```
jboss.server.config.dir
jboss.home.dir
```

From https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Command+line+parameters the table under the heading "Standalone".

Comment: Do you mean just see them via CLI? Like the output from `/core-service=server-environment:read-resource(recursive=true,include-runtime=true)`?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I mean more like using the values of the different variables available. In JBoss CLI.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can do `/:resolve-expression(expression=${jboss.home.dir})`. Is that what you're looking for? If it's just paths, `/path=*:read-resource` would work.